# Prevent page load after javascript confirm dialog

Tags: javascript

On the results portion of an employee registration page, I need to check for duplicates prior to completing the registration.  So, variables are posted to the results page and I query the database 3 different ways to find any similarities:

1st case:  if same SSN, I show confirm box which either redirects to the existing chart if OK is clicked or redirects back to registration to "try again" if Cancel is clicked.

2nd and 3rd case:  if registrant has a last name or first name plus same date of birth of anyone in the database, a choice is given - OK redirects to a list of all those persons or CANCEL will continue the results page and register the new employee.

The 1st case works fine because in either case I am redirecting AWAY from the results page.  For second and third cases though, if OK is clicked, the page IS redirected but not before completing the registration - which I don't want to happen.

Here's the code:

```
/*Primary Check*/
$sql_personnel_check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 'SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE Ssn = "'.$ssn.'"');
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql_personnel_check);
if ($count > 0) {
    $row_personnel_check = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_personnel_check);
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    if (confirm('Based on the Social Security Number entered, a record for this candidate already exists.  Please click OK to view the record.  Click CANCEL to go back and re-enter details.')) {
                        window.location.href='rainmaker.php?EId=<?php echo $row_personnel_check['EId']; ?>';
                    }
                    else {
                        history.go(-1);
                    }
                </script>

        <?php
                exit;   
            }
            /*Secondary Check*/
            $sql_personnel_check_2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 'SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE Lname = "'.$lname.'" AND Dob = "'.$dob.'"');
            $count_2 = mysqli_num_rows($sql_personnel_check_2);
            if ($count_2 > 0) {
                $row_personnel_check_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_personnel_check_2);
        ?>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    if (confirm('Based on LAST NAME and DATE OF BIRTH combination entered, a record for this employee may already exist.    Click OK to view possible matche(s).  Click CANCEL to create a new record.')) {
                        document.location.href='personnel_report.php?Dob=<?php echo $row_personnel_check_2['Dob']; ?>&Lname=<?php echo $row_personnel_check_2['Lname']; ?>';

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                </script>
        <?php

            }
            /*Tertiary Check*/
            $sql_personnel_check_3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 'SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE Fname = "'.$fname.'" AND Dob = "'.$dob.'"');
            $count_3 = mysqli_num_rows($sql_personnel_check_3);
            if ($count_3 > 0) {
                $row_personnel_check_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_personnel_check_3);
        ?>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    if (confirm('Based on FIRST NAME and DATE OF BIRTH combination entered, a record for this employee may already exist.   Click OK to view possible matche(s).  Click CANCEL to create a new record.')) {
                        document.location.href='personnel_report.php?Dob=<?php echo $row_personnel_check_3['Dob']; ?>&Fname=<?php echo $row_personnel_check_3['Fname']; ?>';
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                </script>
        <?php


            }
?>
```